# Is there a magical solution/cable/box to simply mirror and stream everything that happens on my TV screen to my iPad mounted on my bed?

Tags: ipad, television

The title says it all. My problem is:

I can't watch the TV from my bed, but I have my iPad mounted on my bed, right above my face. It is very convenient and comfortable. Now it would be AWESOME if I could also watch TV on my iPad. I can change the channels on the TV using the remote control. All I would need is some kind of solution/cable/box that would mirror my TV screen on my iPad.

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Does your cable provider have an app that allows you to watch?  I don't know where you're located but every provider where I'm located has one of these.

Comment: @fsb you are very correct. It looks like XFinity Stream will do it. Not exactly a TV mirror, but it is something. Let's leave this question to see if there is a mirror solution. I'm curious.

Comment: I have Xfinity as well and I use both their Roku and iOS apps to watch TV almost every day (go Cubs!).